# Traversing the complete array even after finding the string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append, traversal

i'm trying to traverse through the whole array till the end looking for the particular element even if it is found, till yet it is working till it is found for the first time.
Like i have an array named a = [a,b,c,d]//(prodname) and other array of it's ids i = [0,1,1,1] // prodAppid

now what i want is to create an array that will have the items of array a whose id is 1, which should be final = [b,c,d] // TargetProducts1.

till now i'm getting final = [b,b,b], it is not going further. this is my code

```
  for items in prodAppid {

            if var i = prodAppid.index(of: v_targetapplication) {

                print("Product id is at index \(i)")
                print("product Name = \(prodname[i])")
                // product1Text.text = prodname[i]
                //      TargetProducts1.append([prodname[i]])
                TargetProducts1.append(prodname[i])
                print("Target products for this application = \(TargetProducts1)")



            } else {
                print("Product Doesn't exsit for this Application")
                product1Text.text = "No Product available for this Application!"
            }

        }
```

Comment: what is `v_targetapplication`? What is its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let names = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let ids = [0, 1, 1, 1]
let targetId = 1
let targetNames: [String] = ids.enumerated()
    .flatMap { (index, id) -> String? in
        return targetId == id ? names[index] : nil
    }
```

The problem of your code is `if var i = prodAppid.index(of: v_targetapplication)` which always return the first index which `v_targetapplication` is found, which is `1` in your case.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks.